# Ruby on Rails cannot "start server" because of "uninitialized constant SampleApp"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a application in Ruby on Rails, and I changed my version of Rails and Rake. `rails server` does not work anymore:

```
~/sample_app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant SampleApp (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /home/sara/Documents/M1/s8/web avancé/projet/sample_app/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/sara/Documents/M1/s8/web avancé/projet/sample_app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what version of rails did you update to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695705/ruby-on-rails-micheal-hartls-chapter-5-something-strange   - check this if it helps

Comment: Can you check the module line in config/application.rb in case of any syntax errror.

Comment: that's what i have in gemefile: gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run bundle again to update to the newer versions of rails and rake.

Comment: i'm using the same database (sqlite3)

Comment: Did you run rake db:migrate again? As well as bundle?

Comment: when i run  rake db:migrate again i have :rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.

Comment: did you change the version of rake in your gemfile and run bundle before rake db:migrate?